# ListView single selection change and drag event

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to understand sequencing of property changes and mouse events inside ListView.

1. To detect a change is there a difference between observing selectedIndex vs selectedItem?
2. To drag and drop ListView items is there any difference between registering onDrag.. events against ListView vs each ListCell?
3. Is there any scenario where a "onDragDetected" event would be received before the selection model (which I'm observing) is updated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To detect a change is there a difference between observing
>   selectedIndex vs selectedItem?

Not really; I think this is just a matter of whichever is the most convenient for you to use.

> To drag and drop ListView items is there any difference between
>   registering onDrag.. events against ListView vs each ListCell?

I would advocate for registering with the `ListCell`. There's no direct way to check a mouse event on the `ListView` and then determine which cell the mouse event occurred on. You would have to fall back on the selected item, and that's not really semantically the same thing. (For example, how would you handle drag on empty cells, which wouldn't change the selection...?)

> Is there any scenario where a "onDragDetected" event would be received
>   before the selection model (which I'm observing) is updated?

That's implementation dependent. I *think* the current implementation uses a `mousePressed` event to handle selection (though I'm not certain), so it should trigger before the drag is detected, but do you really want to rely on that implementation not changing in a future release?

IMHO, relying on the selected item just feels wrong here. It's semantically different to what you want: you actually want to know "which item the user clicked on", not "which item is selected". Sure, the two are related, but they're not the same thing, so in a way you'd be introducing a dependency on the selection API that should be independent of the thing you're trying to achieve. That is most definitely an opinion, though. Your mileage may vary...

Comment: I agree. Also BehaviorSkinBase defines the mouse event handler and ListViewBehavior handles mousePressed which updates the selection model and focus. Scene contains the dnd stuff and it appears the gesture could be initiated on a mousePressed event.